# Postfix TLS over SMTP - RCPT TO prompts renegotiation then 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients

Tags: debian, ssl, postfix, smtp, tls

I've setup ispconfig3 on my debian six server, and here is a little smtp over ssl:

The server is postfix

```
AUTH PLAIN (LOL!)
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful

MAIL FROM: lol@lol.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: lol@lol.com
RENEGOTIATING
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=NSW/L=Sydney/O=Self-Signed Key! Procees with caution!/OU=Web Hosting/emailAddress=postmaster@lol.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=NSW/L=Sydney/O=Self-Signed Key! Procees with caution!/OU=Web Hosting/emailAddress=postmaster@lol.com
verify return:1
DATA
554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
```

but, the thing is, if I just do a vanilla telnet over port 25 I can authenticate and send mail like a madman... hopefully this is enough information! (as opposed to 'mail.app can't handle ssl!')

Comment: Not by a long shot. Provide the output from `postconf -n` and the relevant part of your mail log (the part containing the entire transaction from beginning to end).

Comment: Have you tried another `RCPT TO: lol@lol.com`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exim TLS and Secure SMTP](http://serverfault.com/questions/308385/exim-tls-and-secure-smtp)

Comment: Ooh, I like the automatic comments when you flag as a dupe, nice touch.  It's not super obvious that the questions are duplicates since they're using different MTAs and @lol didn't say that he was using s_client to test, but he is, and they are =)

Comment: really, you're beautiful people. you can have a doctorate in methods in computing but if you simply are not well versed in *using programs* you still need community help! I <3 stack overflow. In terms of the actual duplicate post - what should I do? (since the tags and the title in no way reflect what is actually going on in the tty) ...?

Comment: re: the dupe...  I'd leave the question alone.  Its completely different wording for the same problem may help other users find it.  If the community wants it closed as a dupe, they can vote for it to be closed (as I did).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Pressing "R" in an s_client session causes openssl to renegotiate](http://tumbleweed.org.za/2007/07/17/sclients-r-feature).  Try entering "rcpt to:" instead of "RCPT TO".

You might also try tools that are more suited to SMTP-specific testing, such as [Tony Finch's smtpc](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~fanf2/hermes/src/smtpc/) or [swaks](http://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/).

Comment: +1 for case sensitivity... you're never too old to forget what is and isn't case sensitive!

Comment: To be clear, s_client is just wrong here.  You were correct in principle for using "RCPT TO".  It's completely braindead that a plain text "R", in a tool that's made for typing text into, causes a renegotiate.  The fact that you can get around it by using "rcpt to" is just a way to work around the bug/poor implementation decision in s_client.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind - I'm migrating from a play server -> a production one (with real ssl!) and so I haven't used all the security tools before, just learned about the unsecured transport protocols :)

Comment: Oh my goodness. OpenSSL, what did you smoke? :'(

Comment: It’s behavior that *could* be useful, but on by default? When I saw the message I assumed the renegotiation was caused by the server and there was a bug there. (Sorry for this “me too!” post)

Comment: Another workaround is to use `openssl s_client -quiet`, which suppresses the interactive interpretation of `R` and `Q` characters.

Comment: o-m-g saved my day

Comment: This only happens if R is on the start of the line.  Note that the "MAIL FROM" command didn't do a renegotiation.

Comment: `MAIL FROM:` and `DATA` commands can be sent as upper case, but `RCPT TO:` must be sent in lowercase like this `rcpt to:`. Someone not in mood for too much testing before releasing :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a design flaw in openssl. As @jj33 alludes, the R at the beginning of a line causes openssl to renegotiate.

Start openssl s_client with the `-quiet` option. I use:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -quiet -connect $HOST:$PORT
```

Granted, you will not see as much debugging output for the certificate. If it fails to verify the cert, you may need to add that option.

Hat tips:

- 200_success
- jj33

https://serverfault.com/a/336657/238998

I didn't mean to steal your answer, but I thought it better if there is an actual answer which fully explains the work-around, rather than for people to fish in comments.